# 7zip CLI switches to achieve the same result then in the GUI

Tags: windows, command-line, 7-zip, gui

Most of the time I use the GUI for zipping stuff with 7zip.
Now I have to batch for about 100 files.
The result between the CLI settings and GUI settings is not the same.

[image: GUI Settings]

CLI Settings:

```
7z a -t7z -mx9 [ArchiveName.7z] [FilesToZip]
```

With the GUI I get:

[image: GUI Result]

With the CLI I get:

[image: CLI Result]

I couldn't find the switch for the CLI that makes the block size solid like in the GUI.
The result is an archive that is twice as big then with the GUI settings.

Is there a way to obtain the same result with the CLI ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the command that you want:

7z a -t7z -m0=lzma2 -mx=9 -mfb=64 -md=64m -ms=on -mmt=1 archivename.7z Filetobearchived

-mx=9: Ultra.

-mfb=64 : Word size 64.

-md=64m : Dictionary size 64MB.

-ms=on : Solid archive.

-mmt=1 : 1 CPU thread.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).